# create httpserver using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

iam new to node.js am trying to creating a http server and spawn a child process.

see the code

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200);
  switch(req.url) {

        case '/vm/start':
            req.on('data', function(data) {             
            console.log("hello");
                console.log(data.toString());
                exec('CALin.exe', function(err, data) {     
                    console.log(err)
                    console.log(data.toString());


});
                    res.end('');
                });
            });

            break;
    }
});

server.listen(9090);
console.log("Server running on the port 9090");
```

while i trying to run the above code using this url `http://172.16.2.51:9090/vm/start` am getting nothing.and browser showing connection reset problem
I dont know why this is happening

```
node server.js

Server running on the port 9090
```

Comment: can you try http://localhost:9090/vm/start

Comment: possible duplicate of [client server communication using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700890/client-server-communication-using-node-js)

Comment: Remove the exec call and see if that works. For me it doesn't reset connection without it.

Comment: i need that exec call

Comment: shouldn't the `res.end('');` be in the exec callback ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no data being sent in the request so the `data` event does not get triggered and therefore `res.end` never gets called and the request times out. Add a listener for the requests `end` event and then call `response.end`.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in a js file and run it

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write("<!DOCTYPE "html">");
response.write("<html>");
response.write("<head>");
response.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
response.write("</head>");
response.write("<body>");
response.write("Hello World!");
response.write("</body>");
response.write("</html>");
response.end();
});

server.listen(9090);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Run  this code as

```
 node web_server.js
```