# node.js function callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to `node.js` i don’t know how to perform the below operation in `node.js`

```
var data ="sampledata", name="testname", id=1;
myTask(data,name,id);

function myTask(data,name,id){
     var job = jobDetails(id,data)
}
function jobDetails(id,data){
    // some operations
    return jobs
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Node.js *is* JavaScript.

Comment: i want to perform the above operation using node.js

Comment: node.js *is* JavaScript. The only real difference is the host interface  (e.g. headless and different event sources).

Comment: @Sush You *just did*. What didn't work? (Besides being uninformative pseudo-code with unbound identifiers.)

Comment: "The above operation" can be performed using Node.js exactly as-is. Your question is like "How do I say 'Muy bien' in Spanish?"

Comment: Also, it has nothing to do with jQuery, and you don't have any callbacks in your code.

Comment: i dont know how to perfrom callback in above code

Comment: Let's take Javascript, You need callback when you try to get answer/result from the function within setTimeout/setInterval. Otherwise you don't need callback. Same things is happening in Node.js but little tricky. Take a look some basics documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the stunned silence is that it's pretty much impossible to answer your question in its current form. But I'll give it a shot anyway.

Most of the time you don't perform callbacks. You might pass a function of yours to an API and at some point it calls your function back. It is thus the API that is performing the callback, not you. As an example, here's one way to use node.js's FileSystem API:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', {encoding:'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The third parameter is a function, commonly referred to as a callback. The `fs.readFile()` function sets up the I/O and returns immediately. At some future point, the I/O completes and calls back the function you passed in (hence the term *callback*), supplying an error code and possibly the data, at which point your function can do what it wants with it.

If you want to *perform* a callback yourself, you write a function that takes a function and calls that function back, e.g.:

```
function pass_double_x_to(x, cb) {
    var two_x = 2 * x;
    cb(two_x);
}

pass_double_x_to(21, function(tmol) {
    console.log("zOMG, " + tmol + "!");
});
```

Now it is your function, `pass_double_x_to`, that is performing a callback on `function(tmol) { … }`. This is actually a pretty silly use of callbacks because your function could just return double-x. Using the callback makes life more complicated for no good reason.

The reason `fs.readFile()` and many other node.js APIs use callbacks is that it performs almost all blocking operations asynchronously so that it doesn't block the main thread, which would make your entire server pause while the OS goes off and fetches the file. So, instead of waiting for the file to be read and return the contents, it begins an asynchronous I/O operation and immediately returns so your program can go off and do other things (like service other connecting clients) while the I/O is in progress in the background. You pass the callback to `fs.readFile()` so that the underlying I/O subsystem knows what to do with the data when it finally arrives, because by then, the main thread has gone off on other adventures. This still makes life more complicated (sometimes horribly so), but it does so for a good cause.

Comment: thank you so much for your brief explanation

Comment: @Sush: It wasn't *that* brief. :-). But you're welcome anyway.

Comment: could you please to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701807/create-httpserver-using-node-js